# Writing a network Scanner with python using scapy

Tags: python, pycharm, scapy

I am writing a simple network scanner with python using scapy following is my code :

```
import scapy.all as scapy



def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)

scan("192.168.1.1/24")
```

Error I am getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ipScanner.py", line 10, in <module>
    scan("192.168.1.1/24")
  File "ipScanner.py", line 8, in scan
    scapy.arping(ip)
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 648, in arping
    filter="arp and arp[7] = 2", timeout=timeout, iface_hint=net, **kargs)  # noqa: E501
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 553, in srp
    filter=filter, nofilter=nofilter, type=type)
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 242, in __init__
    super(L2bpfListenSocket, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 62, in __init__
    (self.ins, self.dev_bpf) = get_dev_bpf()
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/core.py", line 114, in get_dev_bpf
    raise Scapy_Exception("No /dev/bpf handle is available !")
scapy.error.Scapy_Exception: No /dev/bpf handle is available !
Exception ignored in: <function _L2bpfSocket.__del__ at 0x105984c20>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 139, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "/Users/omairkhan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/bpf/supersocket.py", line 211, in close
    if not self.closed and self.ins is not None:
AttributeError: 'L2bpfSocket' object has no attribute 'ins'
```

Can anyone please help understand it.
NOTE: I am running it on mac OS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['L3PacketSocket' object has no attribute 'ins' when using send command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55881295/l3packetsocket-object-has-no-attribute-ins-when-using-send-command)

Comment: @RossJacobs not clear that it is a permissions issue, as in the linked thread

Answer (score -1):

I wrote this exact program when I first started programming with matching syntax, and it ran correctly on my systems when run as administrator. I develop on Linux and Windows rather than Mac, but I will offer what I can.

Are you running this script through your IDE or calling it from the shell?

I recommend only running it from the shell. This simply gives you more control over the files like specifying which version of python the script is, and if you need administrative privileges for a script, you can elevate the script permissions in the shell.
Also, in my OS, I was taught to always use, and have experienced the mistakes of forgetting this, always add:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

as the first line of every script. At least in Linux, it tells the PC how to treat the file (it tells it to treat the file as a python file--yes I acknowledge that its already running it as python). I would check to see if that is valid for MacOS file system.

Most of what I have recommended so far comes down to no `/dev/bpf` handle is available, only ever being an issue for me when I'm not running script as an administrator (although Linux states permission denied). And I shouldn't leave out that using Anaconda on Windows in the past (before I understood the structure of my file systems) prevented me from using common modules like pygame and scapy. I could only guess in that case Anaconda prevented the PC from knowing where to find every piece of that module by making the computer think it had its own one of that module under Anaconda directory when it was in a different PATH.

Comment: Avoid writing such long paragraphs in answer.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, thank you. @AjinkyaDhote

Comment: Adding full-stops where appropriate would also help.